# Pushing folder with GIT Bash to Appharbor is not pushing subfolder

Tags: git, bash, user-interface, push, appharbor

I'm new to Appharbor and GIT so there' some weeks I've been trying to push my ASP.NET MVC 4 application to Appharbor but I'm not having success. I already tried to get some help from their support but they also [don't understand what is possibly happening in my case](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/24265-systemiofileloadexception-the-given-assembly-name-or-codebase-was-invalid-hresult-0x80131047).

I created a new application in Appharbor just following their [oficial tutorial steps](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/deploying-your-first-application-using-git) but a subfolder of the folder I'm pushing is not been pushed so I'm getting some build erros when Appharbor tries to build it.

The structure is:
1)  CarpuProject/
2)  |-  CarpuProject.sln
3)  |-  CarpuProject/
4)  |-  |-  CarpuProject.csproj

The folder been pushed is (1) and the refered subfolder is (3).

Anyone could help me with it? If your suggestion is "Just push (3)", I'd like to ask for some tips or a link to any tutorial which teaches how I could push a subfolder through GIT Bash or GIT Gui.

I thank you alot in advance! It's really stressing me as I can't find an answer ;/

Comment: Have you added the .csproj file to version tracking? What does it say when you write ``git status`` in your git bash while you're in the repository path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With git you do not push any folders. You only push commits.

A commit contains (in addition to some meta information) whatever file you added to it.

Therefore you first have to use `git add` to add some files, then `git commit` to make a commit out of the added files and then push the commit to a remote repository.

If you suspect, that some files have not been pushed, then they are probably not part of the commit. Use `git status` to check if you forgot to add any files.

You can also do a local clone to have an idea what will get pushed: `git clone local/project/dir newdir` will clone your repository to a new directory. Assuming that you did not use any branch beside master, you will see the files as they appear on the server.